# How to create fade and animation hover

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout, muse

I just create a great hover effect for text in Adobe Muse.

See the sample here: http://dash.com.pl/test/test.html

But now I need to gain the same effect of the traditional method by using html/css and js.

I don't know how to get on with it.

Is anyone here, who could help me with this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible using css and js. There's no effect on the underline css property. I'm not sure though but you might want to start looking for something else.

Comment: Fading the colors is fairly straightforward with jQuery (and the Color plugin). The moving underline can't be done as an underline; however, you might try creating a zero-width, one-pixel-high `<div>` underneath the text and animate that instead.

Comment: Yes it's possible - I'm currently making it for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using HTML, CSS and JavaScript - with the help of the jQuery library and jQuery UI (which is used for the colour fading effect).

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sfk35/) !

**Javascript:**

```
var speed = 200;
var line_width = $(".wrapper span").width();
var initial_colour = $(".wrapper span").css("color");

$("span").hover(function() {

    $(this)
        .not(":animated")
        .animate({color:"#0c0"}, speed);

    $(".line", this)
        .not(":animated")
        .animate(
            {
                "width": line_width,
                "background-color":"#0c0"
            },
            speed);

}, function() {

    $(this)
        .not(":animated")
        .animate(
            {
                color:initial_colour
            },
            speed);

    $(".line", this)
    .not(":animated")
    .animate(
        {
            "width":"0px",
            "background-color":initial_colour
        },
        speed);

});
```

Comment: It's precisely what I need to. Thank you very much. I have one more question, its possible to add this effect to everything in my site?

Comment: Yes it's possible to add this to anything.  The best way to go around it would be to create it into a function and then apply it to a certain tag (such as an `<a>` tag).

Comment: Thanks, I hope I do this tonight:)